# Bitbucket/Github Repository branch and master branch

Tags: github, repository, bitbucket

I have a question about the branch and master branch in the repository.

If I have 2 different collaborators working on my repository at the same time, and one of them is working on the master branch whereas the other is working on a branch itself, will there be a conflict if both collaborators push the code at the same time?

Will the master branch's pushed codes override the other branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taking about conflict :**

```
 Suppose A and B are two collaborators;
 A working on master branch;
 B working on other branch;
```

In such scenario conflict may come if :

```
 Despite of being at the different branch,
 A and B both are working on the same file like file.php
```

**Taking about override**

```
 If you want to override one branch with another, You can use following command like:
 git merge 'branch_name'
```

that will merge 'branch_name' branch with your current working branch.

Comment: Thank you so much for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a conflict, your post is exactly why branches are used!
The only time you'll have a conflict is if 2 people try to commit the same file in the same branch at the same time.